# Cosntructing a Jobs website

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-rest

I have started developing website like naukri.com and i am using spring boot technology. When applicants register, i need to store the images and documents etc., in MySql database.

Is it right to store the images and documents in MySql database ? How much data can I store in Mysql, ie: how many no of applicants can I store?

I am thinking of using either Mongodb or Cassandra instead of MySql database. When the applicants grow to a bigger size. Which database is used to store large number of applicants documents? Which is the correct database for storing more number of records and retrieval should be fast?

I am thinking of using cloud to store the documents, but i have never used any cloud technology. Could you please help me which database do i need to use or any open source cloud technology I need to use!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your tech stack is up to you. That said, if you use MySQL, then you will have to deal with database clusters as you scale vs a managed solution like Google datastore.

Comment: How does it go with Mongodb or Cassandra. Does it also need clustering if the size of the applicants grow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL and Mogo are two radically different ways of handling data. If you will build your application based on relational database it could be very difficult to migrate to document based database, when the amount of data will be significant.

There's no good answer to your question. Both database engines have some prons and cons.

Comment: Which database will be good for such large data storage, relational or document based like mongo or cassandra

Comment: Depends on what your needs are. I don't really know how big you predict your database will be. I also do not know what is the complexity of the database.

It is hard to compare those two approaches (relational and document based). Non-relational database gives you the simplicity of operating on documents and storing the current state of each application in one place, but if the document grow big (as your documents might be) it might raise some performance issue since you have to retrieve whole document every time you want to do sth with it.